# Are there performance concerns with changeStreamPreAndPostImages enabled?

Tags: mongodb

Are there any performance concerns with enabling change streams with document pre-images and post-images.

Right now I use `.watch()` for `insert` and `updated` and I would really like to see the document before it's `deleted`.

I also already use `Collection.findById()` if I need more details about a document that has been updated so I'm wondering if pre-images or post-images will be a significantly larger load on the MongoDB server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After enabling pre-image, each update to the collection comes with an overhead, as there will be a record added to the collection that stores pre-images. If the rate of updates to the collection is very high, you may notice some impact. Also the collection with pre-images is using storage space. Retrieveing an image into a change stream from this special collection is pretty efficient.